# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/items"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Не загружается картинка к товару. Использую gem "paperclip". Хочу сделать что бы в каждого товара была картина.

```
 # Модель Item
class Item < ApplicationRecord
   has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: '64x64', med: '100x100', 
    large: '200x200' }
   validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: 
    /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end

# migrate
class AddImageToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :items do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

 def self.down
  remove_attachment :items, :image
 end
end

# edit.html.erb
<h1>Edit new item</h1>

<%= form_for @item, html: { multipart: true } do |f|  %>
  <%= render partial: "form", locals: { f: f } %>
  <p></br><%= f.submit "Обновить товар"%></p>
<% end %>

# new.html.erb
<h1>Create new item</h1>

<%= form_for @item, html: { multipart: true } do |f|  %>
  <%= render partial: "form", locals: { f: f } %>
  <p></br><%= f.submit "Создать товар"%></p>
<% end %>


# index.html.erb
<% @items.each do |i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= i.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to i.name, item_path(i) %></td>
    <td><%= i.price %> руб.</td>
    <td><%= i.description %></td>
    <td><%= i.created_at.to_s.sub("2016", "2017") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Удалить", i, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Точно удалить?" }%> </td>
    <td>Рейтинг: <%= i.votes_count %>, <%= link_to "+", upvote_item_path(i) %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag  i.image.url(:med) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Было бы здорово ещё лог ошибок увидеть. На вскидку - проверьте права доступа на папку для картинок.

Comment: Есть подозрение... Покажите роуты. У вас там, случайно, не `resource` вместо `resources`?

Comment: Спасибо Всем, уже разобрался: private 
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:price,:name,:description,:weight,:image)
  end забыл указать :image